# Is there a way of measuring components in circuit?

Tags: measurement, multimeter

I have some old circuit boards full of SMD components that I would like to reuse in my projects. Before going through the trouble of removing any from their old circuits, I would like to know if they are of any value to me by measuring their resistances and capacitances for example. But simply using a multimeter and probing the terminals of one component like a resistor would give the parallel resistance between *all paths* from one terminal of the resistor to another, not just the resistance of the one component across which I have connected my multimeter.

Is there any way to measure single components without removing them from their circuit boards?

Comment: You can't get fully accurate measurements because the current bleeds away to other parts of the circuit. Passives are very inexpensive and not worth recovering. IC's or transistors usually have markings that can help identify them

Comment: Recycling passives is indeed rarely worth it except perhaps for high value capacitors and unique things.  Anyone who is going to work on SMD boards really should get a budget hot air station, not only for spot reflowing when placing parts in stenciled paste, but also because it's the best tool for fixing mistakes, and can be used for transplanting parts as well.

Comment: Cut all relevant copper traces on the PCB to isolate the component and hope there are no hidden vias.

Comment: In many cases, yes you can measure components in circuit, see the duplicate question and answers. Is it easy? No. Is it worth it? Rarely. Is it useful to be able to do it when you have to? Yes. Is it good to know how to do it? Absolutely.